# Using of session in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, edx

I have understood that the use of session is like using a Hash (more or less). When I use the session I set something like session[:sort] = 'title'. However, the app throws me an exception:

undefined local variable or method `session' for MoviesController:Class

That makes me think that I have to set something before I use session, like initialize it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `session` in a class method? You need to use it in an instance method.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know I should use it in a class method. Thanks